# Avoid repeated header in birt report

Tags: eclipse, birt

Is there any way to avoid repeating header after page break in Birt report ? I want header in first page but dont want it in second and third page.How can i avoid repeating header ? I tried to solve the problem by  choosing some option  from page break menu.But it is not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not giving very much information to go on.  What type of control? Is there anything nested?  How about a Screen shot? You mentioned trying to solve it by "choosing some option", not very helpful when trying to diagnose your problem.

The only thing I can suggest is unchecking the "Repeat Header" checkbox in the Page Break tab.

[image: Highlighting the option to "Repeat Header" in the Page Break tab of the BIRT Report Designer IDE.]

Comment: Thank you so much.I did not notice it.

Comment: Is it possible to remove Header from List?